# Can't get value of CheckBox in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

so, i want to get value of my check box in my gridview, but what i get is the value of my last value of check box. ex: if i checked the check box, what i got is checkbox.checked = false. when i uncheck the check box, what i got is checkbox.checked = true.

here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData()
    {
        List<User> retVal = new GetUserSystem().User_GetUser();
        List<String> retVal2 = new GetUserSystem().User_GetAuth(Session["ProjectName"].ToString());
        if (retVal2 != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < retVal2.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < retVal.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (retVal2[i].Equals(retVal[j].username.ToString()))
                    {
                        retVal[j].auth = "Y";
                    }
                    else if (retVal[j].auth == "" && !retVal2[i].Equals(retVal[j].username.ToString()))
                    {
                        retVal[j].auth = "N";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < retVal.Count; j++)
            {
                retVal[j].auth = "N";
            }
        }
        gvUser.DataSource = retVal;
        gvUser.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvUser.Rows)
        {
            var lblUsername = gvrow.FindControl("lblUsername") as Label;
            var checkbox = gvrow.Cells[1].FindControl("cbxAuth") as CheckBox;
            if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                new AddSecuritySystem().User_AddSecurity(lblUsername.Text.ToString(),Session["ProjectName"].ToString(),"Y");
            }
            else
            {
                new AddSecuritySystem().User_AddSecurity(lblUsername.Text.ToString(),Session["ProjectName"].ToString(),"N");
            }
            i++;
        }
        Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
    }
```

and this is the aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Security.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectManagement.Security" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlUser" runat="server" Width="350px" CssClass="CellPadding" BorderColor="#003399" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Style="color: blue; font-size: large;">Security</asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvUser" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" ForeColor="Black">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxAuth" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Auth")).Equals("Y") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbxAuth" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Auth")).Equals("Y") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are talking about webforms, you should not call `loaddata()` on postback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if(!IsPostback)
           {
              loadData();
            }
    }
```

Without checking `IsPostback` on `page_load`, your old data gets loaded again on `button click`, into `gridview` and changing state of checkbox.